# Change request on Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a massive code and I need to change plenty of incidents.

I need to remove all the dashes from the numbers in my code.

example:

I have a list like below (vertical)

```
972-54-2350040 972-58-6299891 972-53-2751891 972-54-2050624 972-50-8341212 972-52-6962686 972-50-2220204 972-50-6655606 972-50-5703009
```

and i need it to be (vertical)

```
972542350040
972586299891
972532751891
972542050624
972508341212
972526962686
972502220204
972506655606
972505703009
```

Can someone help with that issue?

Thanks, 
Koby

Comment: find `-`, replace with nothing, find space, replace with `\r\n`....?

Comment: I don't understand "I have a list like below (vertical)", the example shows a single line! Do you mean "horizontal"?

Answer (score 1):

Capture the numeric components of each entry, then rebuild the output, replacing a single space with a newline:

**Find:**

```
(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)           <-- there is a space at the end of this pattern
```

**Replace:**

```
$1$2$3\r\n
```

or

```
$1$2$3\n
```

the latter on Linux

Answer (score 0):

Do control + f, click on Replace tab, in Find what field enter - and in Replace with field enter nothing, then click on 'Replace All'

Answer (score 0):

Press Control + H.

Place the wanted character into the "Find What" box. In this case put `-` into the box.

Keep "Replace With" box empty

Press "Replace All"

After that press (space) button on your keyboard inside the "Find What" box.
and put `\r` to the "Replace with" box

then click "Extended" on the "Search Mode" list.

and press "Replace All".

returns:

```
972542350040
972586299891
972532751891
972542050624
972508341212
972526962686
972502220204
972506655606
972505703009
```

Comment: I would rather do this in a single step, to avoid possible side effects elsewhere in the document.  In general, the more specific you can make a find/replace, the better off you'll be.

Comment: yes i know but looking in to this question it seems the "Asker" is new in notepad++ and would possibly not get how to do any more advanced searches. And the question states that the "code" is this list. So there should be no "side effects". I'll agree your answer is definitely better.